# Find a Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = |x|; -\infty <x < \infty $ on the region indicated, or prove there is none.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(a) $f(x) = |x|; -\infty <x < \infty $

The way i approach is to take the derivative for x from 0 to infinity which gives me 1 and take the derivative for -x from 0 to negative infinity which gives me negative 1...therefore, since there is not constant can be 1 and -1 at the same time ....my answer is there is no Lipschitz constant which satisfies this condition...is this a right approch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Recall the definition of Lipschitz:

> A function $f$ is Lipschitz if there exists a constant $C$ for which $|f(x) - f(y)| \le C |x - y|$ for all $x, y$.

So in order to tell if $f(x) = |x|$ is Lipschitz, you need to see whether there is a constant $C$ such that
$$\Big||x| - |y|\Big| \le C |x - y|$$

---

As a note, any $C^1$ function with bounded derivative *is* Lipschitz; this isn't quite applicable here, since $|x|$ fails to be differentiable at $0$. But non-differentiability doesn't imply that the function is not Lipschitz.

Comment: is "$$\Big||x| - |y|\Big| \le C |x - y|$$" a version of triangle inequity?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Yes, with $C = 1$.

Comment: could you show me why $$\Big||x| - |y|\Big| \le |x - y|$$ is true?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf It's a useful exercise to try proving it; you can check your efforts against the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: the proof you refer to have double absolute sign...will that make a difference?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Trace the steps of the proof with a usual absolute value (the double bars refer to a norm, but the logic is identical).

Comment: got it...I am also wondering any constant bigger than 1 will also work right?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.  A function can be Lipschitz without being differentiable, and it can be differentiable without being Lipschitz.

For this problem, $1$ will work as a Lipschitz constant.

Why?  Note that for any $x,y$, we have
$$
\left||x| - |y|\right| \leq |x-y|
$$

Comment: any constant bigger than 1 will work right...but the way, is $||x| - |y|| \le |x-y|$ a version of triangle inequity? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: In fact $C = 1$ exactly works just fine.  What I've used is sometimes called the ["reverse-triangle inequality"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: I am wondering any number bigger than 1 will also work right?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes!  Any number bigger than $1$ will also work, and since our goal is just to say that there is *some* $C$, it's okay to have $C = 2$, or $C = 100$ for example.